# Java Base64 Encode with Amazon Services

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, signature, amazon-sns

I am using exact code from here:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AuthJavaSampleHMACSignature.html

to generate a signature for my application.  However, one line of code is not recognized in Eclipse

```
result = Encoding.EncodeBase64(rawHmac);
```

Eclipse is saying it does not recognize the "Encoding" class.  This is the exact error:
The method EncodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Encoding
I've tried importing the following 3 things:

```
javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding;
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
org.omg.IOP.Encoding;
```

However all three of these then tell me they don't recognize the 'EncodeBase64' function.  Does anybody know what import im supposed to use for the code linked above?

Comment: The exact error message is
The method EncodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Encoding

Answer (score 2):

There is Base64 encoding/decoding support in **standard Java**: [javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary%28byte%5B%5D%29). That would be a zero overhead choice.

Answer (score 2):

Note that no proficient Java developer will use an uppercase letter for the start of a method, so if you did not make a typo, you cannot expect to find `Encoding.EncodeBase64` in any standard library. You are better off using another Base 64 encoder/decoder, such as the one found in the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) - which seems to have the best API available to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to encode your `rawHmac` is this one:

```
String result = new String(encode(rawHmac));
```

With this encoding function:

```
  private static char[] encode(byte[] bytes) {
    final int amount = bytes.length;
    char[] result = new char[2 * amount];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      result[j++] = HEX[(0xF0 & bytes[i]) >>> 4];
      result[j++] = HEX[(0x0F & bytes[i])];
    }

    return result;
  }

  private static final char[] HEX = {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
  };
```